# How do I iterate into an object that I send with ajax to my controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, axios

I have this object:

`[{cantidad:1,precio_unitario:3}{cantidad:5,precio_unitario:6}]`

I need to send it to my laravel controller using post with axios.

```
axios.post("compras_listas/a",this.items).then(respuesta=>{
                //reponse code here
            })
```

I know the data is stored in a variable called $request, but I do not know how to access the data that axios is sending.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post your controller's code?

Answer (score 1):

You can post from axios with data as an object whose key can be used to retrieve data in the controller from the $request object

```js
//this.items = [{cantidad:1,precio_unitario:3}{cantidad:5,precio_unitario:6}]

axios.post("compras_listas/a",{payload: this.items}).then(respuesta=>{
    //reponse code here
})
```

Then in the controller method you can access the data as

```php
public function example(Request $request)
{
    $payload = $request->input('payload');

    //rest of the processing in the controller method
}
```